# Не работает фрагмент

Tags: java, android

Main Activity
    package com.hfad.workout;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WorkoutDetailFragment frag = (WorkoutDetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);
    frag.setWorkout(0);
}
}
```

Класс Workout

```
package com.hfad.workout;

public class Workout {
private String name;
private String description;

public static final Workout[] workouts = {
        new Workout("Подтягивания", "5 подходов по максимальному кол-во подтягиваний. Пауза 60 сек."),
        new Workout("Отжимания", "7 подходов по максимальному кол-во отжимания. Пауза 90 сек."),
        new Workout("Приседания", "5 подходов по максимальному кол-во приседаний. Пауза 120 сек."),
        new Workout("Эстафета", "Подтягивания, отжимания, приседания - 3 подхода, пауза 180 сек.")
};

private Workout(String name, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}
}
```

Фрагмент WorkoutDetailFragment

```
package com.hfad.workout;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {

private long workoutId;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    View view = getView();
    if(view!=null){
        Workout workout = Workout.workouts[(int) workoutId];
        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDescription);
        description.setText(workout.getDescription());
       /**TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        title.setText(workout.getName());*/

    }
}
public void setWorkout(long id){
    this.workoutId = id;
}
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при запуске программы, выводиться только заголовок (т.е. "Потягивания"), хотя должно выводиться и описание этих упражнений. Подскажите в чем проблема)

Comment: недостаточно получить ссылку на фрагмент из фрагмент-менеджера, чтобы его увидеть на экране. нужно еще указать где его отображать и сделать коммит. примеров в инете как работать с фрагментами - без преувеличения, миллионы.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)

Comment: в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) все подробно написано